# move_uploaded_file() won't replace existing image

Tags: php

I'm using the script below, so user can upload their profile picture. The first time an image is uploaded (when the image doesn't exist at the location) it works great. However, if  the image is already exist at the path (if the user tries to change the profile picture) the new image won't replace the old one. I do get success for the query.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);

 error_reporting(E_ALL);


require_once('db.php'); 


$name = $_POST['name']; 

   $dir = '../uploadImages/'; 
   $file = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

   $uploadfile = $dir . $file;


    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
    {


        $path = $name; 
        $path .= 'Image.png';       
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET imagePath='$path' WHERE username='$name'");

        if ($query)
        {
            echo 'success'; 
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'error'; 
        }


    }
    else 
    {
        echo mysql_error(); 
    }


 ?>
```

Comment: Did you create the first image through the upload or by creating the file yourself?  If the latter, it maybe a permissions issue.

Comment: In fact, now I think about it, check your PHP version.  I filed a bug about this years ago, and I know it wasn't fixed for years, so it still might not be, or you could be using a version where it isn't fixed.

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_error()` if it fails to move the file? It didn't make any mysql query at the time…

Comment: Have you tried first to remove the existing file?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A better way would be un-linking the file if it exists

```
if(file_exists('your-filename.ext')) {
    chmod('your-filename.ext',0755); //Change the file permissions if allowed
    unlink('your-filename.ext'); //remove the file
}

move_uploaded_files($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 'your-filename.ext');
```

Comment: Not necessarily better. move_uploaded_file should do that itself

Comment: the function isn't called unlink_duplicate_file_then_move_uploaded_file

Answer (score 4):

If `move_uploaded_file` fails, it returns false. In that case, no SQL is executed at all, so `mysql_error`, which is echoed in the `else` branch, indeed won't output an error.

if `move_uploaded_file` fails, it issues a warning, that will become visible depending on your PHP settings. However, this problem doesn't have anything to do with MySQL.

If you try to explicitly delete the target file first, if it exists. Check with `file_exists` and then with `unlink` to delete the file. If `unlink` fails, it's probably a permissions issue than won't allow you to delete or overwrite the file.

Answer (score 3):

No, your logic is wrong.. take a look at the URL of your profile image, either here, in facebook or twitter..do you see they use a fixed predictable name ? They don't, and there is a very good reason for that, you need unique, unpredictable filenames.

Try this:

```
$file = hash('sha256', openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8)) . 'yourallowedextension';
```

Then query the name of the old picture from your database, after that, upload the new pic, if that succeeds, update the user's profile picture in the database and unlink() the old file using the information previously obtained if any.

Ensure that you are not allowing to upload php files or any other nasty stuff, for that you can use php fileinfo extension.

Answer (score 2):

```
$file=$_FILES['image']['name'];
$path="your/location/".$file;
if(file_exists($path)) 
{
  chmod($path,0755); 
  unlink($path);
}
```

Then move the file using `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: You missed a parentheses: `)` after the `file_exists` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this, the new image will be replaced:

```
$sourcePath = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
list($width,$height)=getimagesize($sourcePath);
$uploadedImage = imagecreatefromjpg($sourcePath);
$newImage=imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth,$newHeight); 
imagecopyresampled($newImage,$uploadedImage,0,0,0,0,$newWidth,$newHeight,$width,$height);
imagejpeg($newImage, $destinationPath,100);
```